# Jenkins job is always failing after windows batch command execution script for rerun cucumber tests

Tags: shell, unix, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cucumber-java

I am running cucumber java tests in jenkins job using maven build as below

[image]

After its done in post step under windows batch command execution script I am rerunning failures

mvn clean verify  -Dcucumber.options="@rerun.txt --tags @Retry1" -Dthreadcount="2"

After this step every time execution fails. I have read somewhere that if I add any of the below line it should pass but still it fails every time.

**echo "exit script"**

**true**

**command || true**

**exit 0**

Also added #!/bin/sh at start of script

Please advise.

Comment: Kindly do wrap your samples in CODE TAGS as per forum rules for better visibility in your question thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since this is supposed to be executed on Windows you may try

```
mvn clean verify -Dcucumber.options="@rerun.txt --tags @Retry1" -Dthreadcount="2" & echo note: ignoring exit code
```

or

```
cmd /c mvn clean verify -Dcucumber.options="@rerun.txt --tags @Retry1" -Dthreadcount="2" & echo note: ignoring exit code
```

(sorry, don't have Jenkins with Windows agent to test this at hand).